# How can I derive euclidean distance matrix from gram-schmidt matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

This is my first post, sorry for my naiveness..

I know a basic equation that relates Gram-schmidt matrix and Euclidean distance matrix:

$XX'=-0.5*(I-J/n)*D*(I-J/n)'$

Where $X$ is centered data (is $d \times n$), $I$ is identity matrix, $J$ is a matrix filled with ones (1), $n$ is the number of columns in $X$, and $D$ is the distance matrix (with dimensions $n \times n$).

My question is:

How can I derive Euclidean distance matrix $D$ from this equation? I would like something like:

$D=$ (something ¿?)

For example, I can see that:

$D=-2*inv((I-J/n))*XX'*inv((I-J/n)'$

But $(I-J/n)$ is a singular matrix. I am still interested in some approximation.

Thanks a lot!!

Mark

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Don't be sorry for anything.

Comment: Thanks for the greetings!. It seems that there isn't answer for this simple problem. :(

Answer (score 2):

There are simple linear relationships between an Euclidean distance matrix and a Gramian matrix in both directions.
The linear transformation $G\rightarrow D$ is given by
$$ D = \delta(G)\mathbf{1}^\mathrm{T} + \mathbf{1}\delta(G)^\mathrm{T} - 2G,$$
where $G=XX^\mathrm{T}$, and $\delta(G)$ denotes the diagonal elements of $G$.

Your formula for $G\rightarrow D$ may also be rewritten as
$$ G = -\frac{1}{2}VDV,$$
where $V=I_n-\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\mathrm{T}$ is a geometric centering matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to $A.X.B = Y$ in a least-squares sense is 
$$ X = A^+.Y.B^+ + W - A^+.A.W.B.B^+ $$
where $W$ is arbitrary and $A^+$ denotes the pseudo-inverse of $A$.

In your problem, $A=B$ equals the centering matrix (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix).  You are correct, it **is** a singular matrix, but it has some very useful properties:
$$\eqalign{
C^+ &= C \cr
C^2 &= C \cr
C' &= C \cr
}$$
So solving for $D$ yields
$$ D = -2(C.X.X'.C) + W - C.W.C $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, lynne!. But, I have a doubt. How do I choose W?. You say that it is arbitrary, but when I replace W by identity matrix, the result is different to Distance Matrix.