# Derivative of double centered Euclidean distance matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, euclidean-geometry, matrix-calculus, convex-geometry

I want to do this matrix calculus: Given, a distance matrix of squared Euclidean distances  $D(X)_{n \times n}$ of $n$ points $X \in \mathbb{R}^k$, and given $C_n$, a centering matrix as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix, I want to find derivative of $$-C_n D(X) C_n$$ wrt $X$.  Eqn 1049 or 1050 of chapter 5 'Euclidean Distance Matrix' of this wonderful book here: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/EDM.pdf which gives a simplification of $D(X)$ could be useful.

My guess is the gradient would be $-C_n(\cdot)$ where the placeholder $(\cdot)$ would be the r.h.s of eqn 1049. I could be wrong. Nevertheless, I was looking for simpler representations of this derivative so that its wieldy to use in computations and as part of a larger result or analysis.

$-0.5*C_n D(X) C_n$ occurs in technique of 'classical multidimensional scaling' and is related to Gramian matrix representation as can be seen in here as well [Calculating Gramian matrix from Euclidean distance matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882130/calculating-gramian-matrix-from-euclidean-distance-matrix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gram and Distance matrices of the data matrix $X$ are
$$\eqalign{
G &= X^TX,\qquad g={\rm diag}(G) \\
D &= g{\tt1}^T + {\tt1}g^T - 2G \\
}$$
The centering matrix is
$$\eqalign{
C &= I - \frac{{\tt11}^T}{n},\qquad C{\tt1}=0,\quad{\tt1}^TC=0^T \\
}$$
Write the function of interest and calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
F &= -CDC  \;=\;  2CGC \\
dF
 &= 2C\,dG\,C \\
 &= 2CX^TdX\,C + 2C\,dX^TXC \\
}$$
Then use [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) to flatten the matrices and obtain the gradient as a matrix.
$$\eqalign{
df &= \Big((2C\otimes CX^T) + (2CX^T\otimes C)K\big)\,dx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
 &= 2\left(C\otimes CX^T\right) + 2\left(CX^T\otimes C\right)K \\
}$$
where $K$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the Kronecker product.

Without vectorization, the gradient is a matrix-by-matrix derivative (a fourth order tensor).

I can provide an expression for that, but I doubt you'd find it useful.

Let $Y=XC,\,$ then the tensor gradient expression is
$$\frac{\partial F_{ij}}{\partial X_{kl}}=2C_{il}Y_{kj}+2Y_{ki}C_{lj}$$

---

#### Update

Perhaps this a better way of writing the tensor. 
$$\eqalign{
H &= C\star Y \qquad&\big({\rm Dyadic\,Product}\big) \\
H_{ijkl} &= C_{ij}Y_{kl}& \\
\frac{\partial F_{ij}}{\partial X_{kl}}
  &= 2\big(H_{ilkj} + H_{jlki}\big)\quad& \\
}$$

Comment: What is lower case x? Is it X_ij? Id be curious to look at the tensor version as well!

Comment: Follow the _vectorization_ link.

Comment: Got it. Entry in vectorized version of X